# Assignment inside IF statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

```
string Newfilename;
string Defaultfilename;

        protected void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExt =
                Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);


            if (fileExt == ".xls" || fileExt == ".xlsx")

                try
                {
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
                    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    string fileLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", Server.MapPath("upload/"), id, extension);
                    ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs( fileLocation );
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                    Newfilename = fileLocation;
                    Defaultfilename = Path.GetFileName(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                }
            else
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Please choose excel file";
            }

        }
    }
```

I am trying to assign values to Newfilename and Defaultfilename (inside "try", after naming uploaded file), but they stay empty.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is currently happening?

Comment: "I failing" doesn't really tell us what's going wrong... could you be more descriptive? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but "obvious" wouldn't be the word I use here. Maybe you could try to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to assign values to string Newfilename and string Defaultfilename, and nothing is getting assigned, values stay empty.

Comment: I failing to understand the problem

Comment: What is the value of ASPxUploadControl1 when you are in debug mode.. assuming you are debugging this

Comment: @el ninho. Set a breakpoint. Step through it. What's wrong should become obvious. Come back if what's wrong turns out to be something you don't understand and then fully describe what you expected and what you actually saw.

Comment: Server.MapPath("upload/"), id, extension); shouldn't that be Server.MapPath("/upload"), id, extension); or even Server.MapPath("~/upload"), id, extension); so hard to debug peoples code without them putting in what values they have for each variable...GRRRR

Comment: Also What are you doing with Newfilename = fileLocation; Newfilename seems to never be used....

Comment: Ok, it's too late in the day! Deleted my spurious answer!

Comment: @DJKRAZE no values at beginning, empty string, it should be assigned in this IF/ELSE and used later on "uploadcomplete" event.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE NewFilename will be used later. I can't write rest of the code until I solve this.

Comment: not a problem. I reformated your code in the new answer.. also in your first if check what is ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile = false..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code and think about the process that you want .. then Debug the Code.. Test it.. and if you have an Issue then edit your post.. that's what I suggest.. 
If statements should be wrapped with in a code block "{ }" same way that you have Try {} a good rule of thumb for even readability would be to wrap everthing around {} if you have If Else otherwise it makes if hard to read as well as lend assistance.

inside your code where you are declaring the following, make them variables within the method itself

- string fileExt  = string.Empty;
- string extension = string.Empty;
- string id = string.Empty;
- string fileLocation = string.Empty;

so your method would look like this

```
protected void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

    string fileExt  = string.Empty; 
    string extension = string.Empty;
    string id = string.Empty;
    string fileLocation = string.Empty;

    if (ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile)
    {              
         fileExt = Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
         if (fileExt == ".xls" || fileExt == ".xlsx")
         {
           try
           {
             extension = Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
             id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
             fileLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", Server.MapPath("upload/"), id, extension);
             ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs( fileLocation );
             StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
             Newfilename = fileLocation;
             Defaultfilename = Path.GetFileName(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
            }                  
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
         }
         else
        {
          StatusLabel.Text = "Please choose excel file";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Path.GetExtension returns null if the passed value is null and returns string.Empty if the passed value doesn't have an extension.
So please check if the value inside **ASPxUploadControl1.FileName** actually contains something usefull.

If this is not the case then you'll have to look up where the value is set and debug from there to find out why it's not set.

Answer (score 1):

Can you step through the execution?

Does

```
NewFilename = fileLocation;
```

get executed?

If so, what are the values for NewFilename before and after?

This looks like ASP.Net code.
If it is. Is the problem that when you try to use *NewFilename* elsewhere in the code-behind is is blank.
If you are, then *NewFilename* may need to be saved to the session to allow you to use it.

hth, 
Alan.